# Matplotlib is not adding one of the points to the line

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to graph an effective potential with python. The idea is that the yellow dot (below in the figure) signals on the graph, the maximum potential. This point is part of the curve, but when plotting, the line does not pass through it. What could be going wrong?

Plot code:

```
            fig1 = plt.figure()
            plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
            plt.plot(1.477*r, v(u, l), color="white")
            plt.plot([1.477/umin,1.477/umax],[vmin,vmax],'bo', color="gold")
            plt.xlabel("r [km]")
            plt.axis([0, 50, -0.5, 11])
            ax = plt.gca()
            plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: PLease, add the complete code, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: To get the maximum of the curve:  `index_max = np.argmax(v(u, l))` and then `plt.scatter(1.477*r[index_max], v(u,l)[index_max], color='gold')` to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line appears to be quite coarse, so you probably need to increase the number of discretization points:

```
import numpy as np
r = np.linspace(0, 50, 1000)
# NOTE: you have to increase the discretization points on
# the variables u, l too

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(1.477*r, v(u, l), color="white")
plt.plot([1.477/umin,1.477/umax],[vmin,vmax],'bo', color="gold")
plt.xlabel("r [km]")
plt.axis([0, 50, -0.5, 11])
plt.show()
```